# primary key "is part of the object's key" new object DatabaseGeneratedOption.None

Tags: entity-framework

i've this POCO class

```
public class EfectoC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and EF configuration:

```
public class EfectoCMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EfectoC> 
{
    public EfectoCMap()
    {
       // Primary Key            
       this.HasKey(t => t.Id );

       // Properties
         this.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None );
     } 
}
```

Really really simple,

the problem is when i do this:

```
EfectoC efC= new EfectoC();
efC.Id = 44;
```

this exception is raised:
the property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Why happens ? i 've DatabaseGeneratedOption.None so i can write the pk, specially in a new instance.

Any idea?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Id` is not nullable so when you call the constructor with `EfectoC efC= new EfectoC()`, `Id` is set to zero, and Entity Framework does not let you change the primary key once it is set.

You have 2 choices:

Add a constructor that takes the Id as a parameter

```
public EfectoC(int id)
{
   Id = id;
}
```

Make the Id nullable:

```
public int? Id { get; set; }
```